# Doubly linked list: delete a node

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to delete a node in a doubly linked list, but the problem here is that when I have the list: 7-6-5-4-3-2-1, and try to delete 3, I get 7-6-5-4-3, I can't figure out the error. Please help!

```
void RemoveItem(int itm)
{           
    if (Head->item == itm) {
        Head = Head -> Next;    
        cout<<"\nItem is at 1st node & removed\n";flag=1;
    }
    else if (Head->Next == NULL) {          
        cout<<" \n This is 1-node list & item not in it\n";
    }
    else {                  
        node *current, *del = Head; 
        while(del->Next != NULL && del->item != itm) {
            del = del->Next;
        }
        current = del;
        current->Next = del->Next;
        del->Next->previous = current;
        delete(del);
        del->Next = NULL;
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a node you iterate until you reach the node of deletion del then set:
pseudocode:

```
del.prev.next = del.next
```

and

```
del.next.prev = del.prev
```

Comment: @AliZahr Get rid of everything else including setting current to delete and just use this logic

Comment: I did, but now I'm getting into infinite loop :/
Here's the code: while(del->Next != NULL && del->item != itm) {
            del = del->Next;
        }
        del->Next->previous = del->previous;
        del->previous->Next = del->Next;
        delete(del);

Comment: @AliZahr take out && del->item != itm and use a counter

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense:

```
current = del;
current->Next = del->Next;
```

because it is the same as

```
del->Next = del->Next;
```

Try something like this

```
// some global int flag = 0
// some global node* Head pointing to head of list

void RemoveItem(int itm) {           
  if (Head->item == itm) {
    node* del = Head;
    Head = Head -> Next;
    delete(del);    
    cout<<"\nItem is at 1st node & removed\n";
    flag=1;
    return;
  } 
  if (Head->Next == NULL) {               
    cout<<" \n This is 1-node list & item not in it\n";
    return;
  }                   
  node* current = Head;
  node* del = Head; 

  while(del->Next != NULL && del->item != itm) {
    del = del->Next;
  }

  // reached with del->Next == NULL || del->item == itm
  current = del->previous;
  if (del->Next == NULL) {
    // at end of list
    if (del->item != item) {
      // item not found
      // todo: signal error
      return;
    }
    current->Next = NULL;
  } else {
    del->Next->previous = current;
    current->Next = del->Next;
  }
  delete(del);
  flag = 1;
 }
```

Note: I fixed many bugs and tried to keep it within your logic. I would have written it different.